# Workaround for JS Regex lookbehind/lookahead for Safari

Tags: regex, safari, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex in JS `const camel = const camel = /((?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z]))/g;`

It basically tries to find the place before is a upper case char and after is an upper case char with following a lower case char.

Some test cases to verify it works:

Below is the case where I find it hard to have an elegant work around..

`'runUnitTESt'.replace(camel, ' ') = 'runUnitTE St'`

This regex works in Chrome, but not in safari, since it does not support lookbehind/lookahead regex. Spent some time trying to think about a good workaround, but did not find one. Any insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you have a capture group around the 2 assertions. What you can do is change the first lookbehind assertion into a match instead and keep the second lookahead assertion.

```
[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGk2xf/1)

Then in the replacement use the full match followed by a space `$&`

```js
const camel = /[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z])/g;
console.log('runUnitTESt'.replace(camel, "$& "));
```