# Regular Expression - Match all but digits and one decimal Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am making a simple website to get familiar with html, css and javascript. I am a beginner programmer. The regular expression will be used in Javascript.

In my website I currently have a simple percentage calculator. It allows users to input a number and click a button to receive their answer.

My goal is to have the input match everything but digits and allows for only one decimal and no negative numbers.

I have a `onkeyup` event that deletes any characters that aren't described above.
So if you type 'abc' it automatically gets erased. Here is the snippet for reference

```
<div class='child flex-child'>
   <label for="num2">Enter your second number: </label>
   <input type="number" id="num2"
        onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')" >
</div>
```

Accepted formats would be as follows: 1.0, 1, 0.1 etc.
Rejected formats: -1, 12.12.12, .1 <- more than one decimal place

Currently I am using ***/[^\d.]/g*** which works but allows for other decimals.

**EDIT** This seems to work fine but doesn't allow for and decimals. I want it to allow at least 1 but no more. ***`[^\d]+(?=.*)`***

Here is a small list of expressions that I have used.

- /^\d+(.\d+)?/gm
- /\d+(.\d+)/gm
- /[^\d.]/g
- /[^0-9.]/g
- [^\d.]^[^0-9]+
- /^\d+(.\d+)?/gm
- /^\d+(.)?\d+/gm
- (^0*)(^.*)+^\d+(.\d+)?

**These would be fine if in-versed**.

- (^.*)+(^0*)+^\d+(.\d+)?
- /[^\d.]/g
- ^[0-9]..*[\d]{1,}

They don't fully accomplish what I am looking for. I am able to accomplish matching my goal but **I need it in-versed** in order for it to meet my needs.

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thank you.

[Edit] I know global and multiline tags aren't necessary as it is only one line. Kept it there from testing.

Comment: Do you have to do this with a regular expression? Why not use `<input type="number">`, which will only allow valid numbers. You can use `min="0"` to prevent negative numbers.

Comment: @Barmar This is mostly for an educational project to get familiar with regex and some base languages. If I did it the way you suggested that would only work when the button is clicked right? Or would it automatically erase any character that isn't a digit and so on... Thank you for your response.

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Try this SO search `[regex] positive number with decimal` for previous questions about matching numbers like this.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried it and that is what happens. This is why I want to keep my current format and find a working expression. I am still tinkering but guidance is appreciated. I don't want to have to reload the page or click the button to see the effect. I want it to happen as user is typing.

Comment: Did you read the answers to the search I gave? There are many solutions posted.

Comment: @Barmar `42.3333+45e12` is a valid number input. So it's way to flexible for what OP wants.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. None seem to accomplish what I am looking for. This is why I am asking this question. I'm not sure if there is something specific you're referring too but please assume that I already done research before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
/[^\d.]+|(\.\d).+|(\..*)\.|/g
```

For example

```js
const before = '123.45';
const after = before.replace(/[^\d.]+|(\.\d).+|(\..*)\.|/g, '$1$2');
console.log(after);
```

We match and replace either anything which comes after a `.` followed by a digit, or a `.` if there is already a `.` earlier in the string.

`$1` refers to whatever is matched by the first capture group `(\.\d)`, and `$2` refers to whatever is matched by the second capture group `(\..*)`.

Comment: This gives me an error. It says "? The preceding token is not quantifiable".  Thank you for your help regardless. It could be an error on my end.

Comment: @RandomGuy70hz The regex works fine, as shown by the snippet.

Comment: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "

Could it be that I am using safari and not chrome?

Comment: @RandomGuy70hz Yes, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883068/workaround-for-js-regex-lookbehind-lookahead-for-safari).

Comment: @RandomGuy70hz Updated to support Safari also.

Comment: This works great. The only thing missing is it won't allow for numbers like 12.12334. Is this fixable? It only allows for one decimal place after the decimal. I meant allow only one decimal but doesn't matter how many places. Thank you!

Comment: I managed to fix it with [^\d.]+|(\.\d.\.).+|(\..*)\.| Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @RandomGuy70hz You are welcome but your fix looks dubious. Please use "decimal point" rather than "decimal". The regex could be improved if you are clearer about whether leading zeros or a leading `.` are allowed.

Comment: Yes they are allowed. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

`^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]?)$`

```
^       - start at the beginning of the string
(
[0-9]+  - any number of digits to begin with
\.?     - 0 or 1 times a dot
[0-9]?  - 0 or 1 times a digit
)       - make it a group
$       - after the group, the string must end
```

The only problem might be it also accepts `1.` as valid input (otherwise you could never type `1.1` as the script removes the dot on input). But you could do a test when submitting the input to filter that one out.

Comment: Thank you! This works similar to the others but ONLY matches the numbers. This is what I need but completely in-versed so it highlights everything BUT

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achieve.
moreover, why not using `<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.1">` which is simple and better

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#num2');
input.addEventListener('keyup', ()=>{
  if(!(/^[^-a-z]\d{0,}(([.]{1})?\d?){0,}$/gi.test(input.value)) ){
     input.value = '';
  }
})
```

```html
<div class='child flex-child'>
     <label for="num2">Enter your second number: </label>
     <input type="text" id="num2">
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would only work when clicking the button correct? It doesn't auto delete as the user is typing. This regex highlights the correct numbers but I need a regex to match everything but these values. Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: check it now, I think it meet your need

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

## Event Handling and Form Controls

Using `.replace()` on a string from a form control when invoked by an key event handler is tricky. It would be better if you wrap all of your form controls (ie `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc) in a `<form>` and then register the `"input"` event to it (see **Figure I**). `"input"` event is like a key event but it's specialized for form controls so it is triggered immediately when the user types into an `<input>` or selects an `<option>` from a `<select>`.

**Figure I**

```
const form = document.forms.ID_or_name_of_FORM 
// See HTMLFormElement in Reference section

form.oninput = event_handler
//OR
form.addEventListener('input', event_handler);
// See Events in Reference section
```

Also, [inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) are garbage so don't use them.

<s>`<input oninput="event_handler(this.value); return false">`</s>

Once you have `<form>` registered to the `"input"` event, you can design the event handler to delegate any `"input"` event to any element within `<form>` and exclude any element as well. Moreover, this event handling works for dynamically added elements as well. For more details on this programming paradigm refer to the Reference section listing: *Event Delegation*.

### Delegating the "Input" Event

The following examples involve two `<input>`s in a `<form>`, `num1` which accepts only integers and `num2` which accepts integers and floats.

All event handlers pass the Event Object by default:

**Figure II**

```
/*
The Event Object has many properties that reference every aspect 
of the event.
*/
function filterInput(event) {
  /*
  The .target property always references the element the user is
  interacting with.
  */ 
  const data = event.target;
  //...
```

Next, delegate the event to the applicable elements via flow control statements, swithes, tenaries, etc.

**Figure III**

```
//...
  if (data.matches('input')) {
    if (data.id === 'num1') {
      // Filter num1 value so it's always an integer
    if (data.id === 'num2') {
     // Filter num2 value so it's always a float or integer
    }
  }
/*
By specifying what elements react, all other elements are excluded.
*/
```

---

## On the Fly Filtering Input Data

In the event handler we will use a RegExp constructor:

**Figure IV**

```
const rgx = new RegExp(/\D?([.][\d]*)\D?|\D/, 'g');
```

When replacing sub-strings within a string value of an `<input>` while the user is still typing you'll need to tighten the quantifiers down to `?` which is 0 or 1.

**Figure V**

| Tokens | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `\D?` | zero to one non-digit character |
| `([.]\d*)` | literal "." and zero to one digit in a capture group |
| `\D?` | zero to one non-digit character |
| `|` | OR |
| `\D` | one non-digit character |

Note, the RegExp is designed to match each character as it's typed and then remove it. Even the "." and the numbers are removed, but since they are in a capture group `(...)`, they can be recalled as the replacement sub-string with an ID (`"$1"` means first capture group):

**Figure VI**

```
let match = data.value.replace(rgx, '$1');
```

Since `.replace()` actually rips everything out of `.value` string then it places the capture group back in, there are times within that timeframe that `.value` has nothing (0 length) and then of course it ends up a smaller string (length of capture group `"$1"`). So we need to place the caret at the end of the string whenever the `"input"` event is triggered:

**Figure VII**

```
//...    
       let end, match
       //...
       if (event.target.id === 'inputID') {
          match = event.target.value.replace(rgx, '$1');
          event.target.value = match;
          end = match.length;
        }
        event.target.setSelectionRange(end, end);
        event.target.focus();
      }
```

**Example**
**Note:** A positive number is guaranteed since a "-" is always filtered out, even if a "-" was allowed the `min` attribute set at `"0"` also prohibits negative values.

```js
document.forms.calc.oninput = filterInput;

function filterInput(e) {
  const data = e.target;
  const rgx1 = new RegExp(/\D/, 'g');
  const rgx2 = new RegExp(/\D?([.]\d*)\D?|\D/, 'g');

  if (data.matches('input')) {
    let match, end;
    if (data.id === 'num1') {
      match = data.value.replace(rgx1, '');
      data.value = match;
      end = match.length;
    }
    if (data.id === 'num2') {
      match = data.value.replace(rgx2, '$1');
      data.value = match;
      end = match.length;
    }
    data.setSelectionRange(end, end);
    data.focus();
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  font: 2ch/1.2 Consolas
}

input,
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
}

label {
  width: 22.5ch
}

input {
  width: 22.5ch;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<form id='calc'>
  <label for="num1">Enter the 1<sup>st</sup> number:<sup>❉</sup> </label>
  <input id="num1" min='0' placeholder='Positive integer only'> <br>
  <label for="num2">Enter the 2<sup>nd</sup> number:<sup></sup> </label>
  <input id="num2" min='0' placeholder='A float or an integer'><br><br>
  <small><sup>❉</sup>A positive integer only (<i>ex. 156 or 5 or 0</i>)</small><br>
  <small><sup></sup>A positive float or integer (<i>ex. 23.05 or 1 or .6687</i>)</small>
</form>
```

### References

[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

[Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

[HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

**Form Controls**
The following elements can be referenced by `document.forms.ID_or_NAME_of_form.elements.ID_or_NAME_of_Form_Control`

```
<button></button>
<fieldset></fieldset>
<input> 
<object></object>
<output></output>
<select></select>
<textarea></textarea>
```